# i have php styles and script problem its work with some pages and not work with others

Tags: php

please some help 
i have problem with the styles file and scripts files in the header and footer for my website
the header file has the styles files ... and the footer file has the script files
the styles applied and working at the index "home" page but the scripts not working at index page 
the styles and scripts not applied on all other pages.

header file code

```
<?php require_once('config.php'); global $site_info,$index_info;?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $site_info['description']['values'];?>">
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $site_info['keywords']['values'];?>">
<title><?php echo $site_info['title']['values'];?></title>

<!--=====Icon-Font======-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<!--======Bootstrap======-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/owl/owl.carousel.css">

<!--=====Styles=====-->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
```

footer file code

```
<?php global $site_info,$index_info; $social_icons = get_option('','social_links') ;?>


    <footer id="footer">
        <div class="top-footer">
            <div class="container">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="footer-logo">
                            <img src="<?php echo URL;?>assets/images/footer-logo.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                        </div>



                            <div class="footer-about-us">

                            <?php $pages = system::_use_('db')->query("SELECT title , excerpt , thumbnail , url FROM `posts` WHERE `type`='page' AND `id` = 21")->exec()->fetch('assoc') ;?>

                                <h5> <?php echo $pages[0]['title'] ?></h5>
                             <p><?php echo trim_text( $pages[0]['excerpt']  , 222 ) ;?> <a href="<?php echo $pages[0]['url'];?>">More</a></p>

                        </div>



                        <div class="footer-social">
                            <label for="follow">follow us</label>
                            <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $social_icons['facebook']['values'];?>" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
                            <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $social_icons['twitter']['values'];?>" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
                            <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $social_icons['linkedin']['values'];?>" class="fa fa-linkedin"></a>
                            <a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $social_icons['google']['values'];?>" class="fa fa-google-plus"></a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="useful-links">
                                    <h5>useful links</h5>
                                     <?php echo draw_menu('footer_menu',array('ul_class'=>'list-unstyled no-margin no-padding' ,'li_class' => 'col-md-6' , 'link_style' => '<a href="[link]" class="[class]" ><i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>[title]</a>','prepend'=>''));?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="get-in-touch">
                                    <h5>get in touch</h5>
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i><?php echo $index_info['footer_address']['values'];?></p>
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-phone"></i><?php echo $index_info['footer_phone']['values'];?></p>
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-fax"></i><?php echo $index_info['footer_fax']['values'];?></p>
                                    <p><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><?php echo $index_info['footer_email']['values'];?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <div class="subscribe">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
                                            <h5>Subscribe to our mailing list</h5>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                    <div class="input-group">
                                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="your email">
                                                            <span class="input-group-btn">
                                                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">join</button> 
                                                            </span> 
                                                </div>

                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-footer">
            <div class="container">
                <p>All Rights Reseved 2016</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>

</section>

<script src="<?php echo URL;?>assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo URL;?>assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo URL;?>assets/plugins/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo URL;?>assets/js/scripts.0.0.1.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 stLight.options({publisher:"52ea3fed-a0eb-407f-9076-f10c6316dc4e",doNotHash:false,doNotCopy:false,hashAddressBar: false});
</script>

</body>
</html>
<?php
/**
* trims text to a space then adds ellipses if desired
* @param string $input text to trim
* @param int $length in characters to trim to
* @param bool $ellipses if ellipses (...) are to be added
* @param bool $strip_html if html tags are to be stripped
* @return string 
*/
function trim_text($input, $length, $ellipses = true, $strip_html = true) {
//strip tags, if desired
if ($strip_html) {
    $input = strip_tags($input);
}

//no need to trim, already shorter than trim length
if (strlen($input) <= $length) {
    return $input;
}

//find last space within length
$last_space = strrpos(substr($input, 0, $length), ' ');
$trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $last_space);

//add ellipses (...)
if ($ellipses) {
    $trimmed_text .= '...';
}

return $trimmed_text;
}
?>
```

Comment: I think the problem looks like the URLs. Try using `/assets/...` rather than `assets/...` (assuming the assets directory is at the root)

Comment: thank you @Don'tPanic its work with styles but the script not work any idea  .. thanks again

Comment: Do you still have the `<?php echo URL;?>` as part of the script src? If you're changed the path like that then you shouldn't need it.